# Gridview Data Display

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have made a gridview and populated data in it with

```
         Dim Arrays As String() = Functions.runAnalyticsReportSample(100216)

            Dim table As New DataTable()
            Dim colID As DataColumn = table.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(String))
            Dim colReferenceNumber As DataColumn = table.Columns.Add("Case", GetType(String))
            Dim colPart_Name As DataColumn = table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

     For Each line In Arrays

                Dim split As String() = line.Split(","c)

                Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow()


                row.SetField(colID, Integer.Parse(split(0)))
                row.SetField(colReferenceNumber, split(1))
                row.SetField(colPart_Name, split(2))

   table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next

        GridView1.DataSource = table
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

Now I want Part Name as textbox field within gridview, so data can be updated for which I have added Template field

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
             <Columns>
                 <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                     <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>

                 </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
```

I am getting value in textbox field, how do I remove the other column because I am getting to Name columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your GridView.AutoGenerateColumns property. If set to "true" it will automatically generate all columns for the resulting dataset. Set AutoGenerateColumns to false and add the columns you want to display manually.